# How to handle different kind of data getting fron an observable?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I am trying to use switchMap operator. But it should call different http requests based upon the params. So for different http requests the data from subscribe will also be deifferent. How to properly handle that data. Right now i am getting typescript error..My code..

```
ngOnInit(){
 this.route.params.pipe(switchMap(params => {
   if (params === 'friends') {
    return this.http.get('some url to get friendList')
   } else if (params === 'chats') {
    return this.http.get('some url to get chats')
   }
  })).subscribe((result: {message: string, friendList: []} | {message: string, chats: []}) => {
    console.log(result)
  })
}
```

Here basically i am getting different structured data for calling two different api based upon condition. So i am trying to work with the result which i am getting from subscribe like..

```
.subscribe((result: {message: string, friendList: []} | {message: string, chats: []}) => {
    if(result.friendList) {
      // do something
    } else if (result.chats) {
      //do something
    }
  })
```

Here i am getting typescript errors on using like `result.friendList` or `result.chats` . So how should i work with the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the type of the result to **any** and then the conditions will work properly and the typescript will pass without errors.

```
.subscribe((result: any) => {
   if(result.friendList) {
      // do something
    } else if (result.chats) {
      //do something
    }
```

})

if you want to specify the type you can make it with that:

```
{message: string, friendList: [] , chats: []}
```

and when one of the arrays is empty you can check the lengths and reach the condition

Comment: ok...i am using that second approch.. 1 more question because here i am using swichMap operator.. therefor previous http request should be cancelled if before recieving the response i change the param..but when i am trying this with delay operator upon changing params i am getting both the previous and new response..why that is that something to do with delay operator functionality...like it's not actually delaying the http call but only delaying the time between the http call and the respoonse??

Comment: You can try to use debounceTime operator , Emits a notification from the source Observable only after a particular time span has passed without another source emission. (From: https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/debounceTime) if my answers helped you please vote and make is as your answer